Remove Windows line ending without altering timestamp
I have a problem where files transferred into my Solaris 11 server automatically arrive with Windows line endings ^M at the end.
Normally I fix this using this command:
find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} {} \;
It works great and removes all the ^M at the end of all lines, for all files.
The problem is that it also touches the files, which means the timestamps all get changed to the same moment when I ran the command, destroying the real timestamps of the files.
I know about the -p option for cp, but I'm not sure how to preserve timestamps using dos2unix or find.  I also have way too many files to use touch to fix them all after the fact.
How can I remove the ^M from the end of lines in all my files without altering the timestamps?

There may be an option to your ftp client or server that would change line endings as the file is received OR you may find thru research that such a program exists, but can you get it installed? Finally, last  resort, get the producing end to change it? Good luck.

flip does this, and is easily compiled.  There's a source tarball here

As mentioned in the comments, check whether your client supports newline conversion, otherwise, you can do something like this (name it preserve-mtime or similar)
#! /bin/bash
f=$1
t=$(stat -c %y "$f")
dos2unix "$f" "$f"
touch -m --date="$t" "$f"

this resets the modification time (assuming you have that option in touch) and invoke it from find as before
find . -type f -exec /path/to/preserve-mtime {} \;


Thank you, Diego.  I tried to run this script, but got the error touch: illegal option -- date=.  I only have access to basics that come with the Solaris 11 (so nothing like gnu available).  My touch does not have the --date option.

Try man touch and check if you can set the date in any other way
